# Scanner dentro de if - java

Tags: java, condiciones, variables, else, scanner

En este ejercicio quisiera obtener un número del usuario, en caso de ser *mayor a 6* obtener otro número que sea menor a 6 y sumarlos. Asumo que para obtener el segundo número, como lo hice con el primero, debo usar Scanner, pero creo que como se crea una variable local ya no sirve fuera del *if* (y dentro tampoco, lo intente).

Pregunto, ¿Cuál sería la solución?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner numero  = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriba un numero mayor a 6:");
    int n = numero.nextInt();
    String mensaje = "";
    int resultado = 0;
        
    if (n < 6) {
        Scanner numero2 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Escriba un numero menor a 6");
        int n2 = numero2.nextInt();
    } else {
        mensaje = "intentarlo mas";
    }
    
    if (n <6 && n2 > 6) {
        resultado = n+n2;
    } else {
        mensaje = "vuelve a intentarlo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El segundo if nunca se va a ejecutar debido a que n2 solo se crea dentro del primer if. Si se entra al primer if, pues, por decirlo de alguna manera, se destruye la variable n2 y no te permitirá usarla en más ningun lugar durante la ejecución del programa. Es local dentro de ese if. Por cierto, tienes el signo invertido, si quieres preguntar si es mayor, pues usa este >. Prueba mi codigo y dime:

```
Scanner numero  = new Scanner (System.in);
int n, n2;

System.out.println("Escriba un numero mayor a 6:");
n = numero.nextInt();   // este va a ser un numero mayor a 6
String mensaje = "";
int resultado = 0;

if (n > 6) {      // esta es la condicion que propones
    
    System.out.println("Escriba un numero menor a 6");
    n2 = numero.nextInt();     // este va a ser un numero menor a 6
    int sum = n + n2;    // aqui se suman el numero mayor y el numero menor a 6

    System.out.println("El resultado es:" + sum);     //  esto me va a imprimir o mostrar el resultado de la suma
}
if (n = 6){      // en caso de que el numero sea igual a 6  :)
    System.out.println("El numero es 6");
}
else {
    mensaje = "El numero es menor a 6";     // esto es lo que se espera
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es factible usar solo un objeto de la clase Scanner , bien puedes usar el objeto numero dentro de tu condicional,sim embargo debes plantearte que el usuario puede ingresar un dato que nuevamente no cumpla con la condicional, por lo que el uso de if no te resultaría tan conveniente, amenos que crees un metodo que envuelva el Scanner

recomendación : usar un bucle [do while](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-do-while-loop) el cual ejecuta una sentencia de codigo y luego evalua la condicional para repetir dicha sentencia, puede ser interpretada como si el numero que ingreso es mayor a 6 repito la solitud del numero hasta que se ingrese un numero menor a 6

```
Scanner numero  = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n,n2=0;
    int resultado = 0;
    
  //si el numero n es menor o igual a 6 repite el codigo hasta que se ingrese uno mayor   
    do{
      System.out.println("Escriba un numero mayor a 6:");
      n = numero.nextInt();
      if(n<6){System.out.println("vuelve a intentarlo");}
    }while(n<=6);
//si el numero n es mayor o igual a 6 repite el codigo hasta que se ingrese uno menor  
     do{
      System.out.println("Escriba un numero menor a 6:");
      n2 = numero.nextInt();
      if(n2>6){System.out.println("vuelve a intentarlo");}
    }while(n2>=6); 

      resultado=n+n2;
     System.out.println(resultado);
```